# The Trolley Problem: Is it better to kill 1 person or let 5 die?

Tags: halacha, death, health-safety-shmira, priorities, murder

I was recently reading about [the Trolley Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trolley_problem)

> A trolley is running out of control down a track. In its path are five people who have been tied to the track by a mad philosopher. Fortunately, you could flip a switch, which will lead the trolley down a different track to safety. Unfortunately, there is a single person tied to that track. Should you flip the switch or do nothing?

I could imagine one could come up with all sorts of similar cases (e.g. shooting down a hijacked plane is one variation I could think of).

My question is: what would Judaism say in such cases?

Comment: There's a JLI class that deals with this issue. I think it's this one: http://vimeo.com/7723694 and I once heard a recording of the class, I think it was here: http://www.torahlp.com/audio.htm?JLI-Talmudic-Ethics-33 - It is connected to the Rambam mentioned in the second half of this answer: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/8787/which-actions-are-prohibited-even-to-save-a-life/8803#8803

Comment: @Menachem. Maybe you should copy/paste that answer here. Or perhaps call this one a duplicate?

Comment: @HodofHod: It isn't an exact duplicate, and this question touches an aspect covered in that question from a different angle. Also, that JLI class explicitly discusses the Trolley Problem, and I don't remember all the details.

Comment: @HodofHod Remember duplicates only apply to questions. Many questions may have the same answer, but they are not necessarily dups...

Comment: Throwing the switch is indirect; shooting down a plane is direct.  I would expect the answers to be different.

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/3646/would-halacha-permit-bombing-auschwitz

Comment: Shooting down the plane would be more akin to blowing up the trolley (which is presumably carrying passengers).

Comment: The trolley problem is more related to the crashing airplane problem in which the pilot cannot avoid a crash, but he can divert the plane from a heavily populated are to a more sparsely populated neighborhood and reduce the number of deaths (crashing into a single house instead of a high-rise apartment building, for example). He will almost definitely attempt to do that.

Comment: Rabbi Tatz has a shiur on morality that discusses this case specifically: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZT2GrCzzPeI

Answer (score 10):

I think the general view is that is forbidden to flip a switch to cause the death of 1 person to prevent 5 other people from dying. Judaism does not just take the utilitarian view to just look at the ends and ignore the means involved, especially when dealing with committing a sin such as murder. (See [Does the end justify the means](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/9993/does-the-end-justify-the-means).) Therefore it would be better to "shev v'al ta'aseh" rather than commit an act of murder. After all "mai chazis" that the 5 people's lives are more valuable than the one person's life? (See Pesachim p. 25) You are not God to be able to make such judgements.

I think this would hold true even if it was only a case of grama and one would not be liable for the death penalty for killing the person. The accepted halacha holds that the 3 cardinal sins are "yehareg v'al ya'avor" even when they are just "abuzraya". Therefore even though one would only be committing an abuzraya of murder, it would still not be allowed.

The case in Yerushalmi and Tosefta on Terumah (which the Rambam in Yesodei haTorah is based on) are discussing a much more complicated case involving enemies and betrayal, uncertain results, and the death of the person in question either way. Therfore I do not know how easily it could be applied to this case.

As for a shooting down a hijacked plane, R' Bleich just published an article in Traditon on this topic which forbids it, which I'm sure quotes many more sources. His view is summarized by [R' Broyde](http://www.jewishpress.com/pageroute.do/49607):

> Rabbi Bleich's essay represents his view that the sanctity of innocent
>   life - not in wartime - is very profound. Many other halachic
>   authorities adopt the view that at least in wartime one certainly can
>   kill innocent people to save the lives of the multitudes.

Unless one can somehow consider the entire plane to  have a din of a rodef, it seems difficult that one can say we can directly go and kill everyone on the plane beforehand (although the fact that they will die soon anyways does make it different than the trolley case) . R' Broyde seems to say that different rules apply during war, but I would normally assume this applies to enemy civilians, not captives.

Comment: Note: I just noticed this very related question here: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/3646/would-halacha-permit-bombing-auschwitz

Answer (score 6):

Rambam Yesode HaTorah 5:5

"If gentiles tell [a group of] women: "Give us one of you to defile. If not, we will defile all of you," they should allow themselves all to be defiled rather than give over a single Jewish soul to [the gentiles].

Similarly, if gentiles told [a group of Jews]: "Give us one of you to kill. If not, we will kill all of you," they should allow themselves all to be killed rather than give over a single soul to [the gentiles].

However, if [the gentiles] single out [a specific individual] and say: "Give us so and so or we will kill all of you," [different rules apply]: If the person is obligated to die like Sheva ben Bichri, they may give him over to them. Initially, however, this instruction is not conveyed to them. If he is not obligated to die, they should allow themselves all to be killed rather than give over a single soul to [the gentiles]."

Comment: -1 Please explain how you connect Rambam to this specific case when only one person should decide. Unless the citation covers the exact case presented it makes little sense as people can arrive at different conclusions.

Comment: Please explain how you see what "*Give us one of you*" mean. Who exactly "gives"? It appears that those Halochos are specifically in Yesodey Hatora and not in Hilchos Rotzeach to signify vague moral principles and not specific Halochos.

Comment: What about fighting back?

Answer (score 3):

There don't seem to be any classical Jewish texts that discuss a comparable scenario until the Rabbi Avraham Y. Karlitz (Chazon-Ish Yoreh De’ah, Hilchot Avodat Kochavim 69; Sanhedrin, Sec. 25) in the 20th century - who deliberates a case of “diverting the arrow” and even he was inconclusive. However, the Rabbi Eliezer Waldenberg (Tzitz Eliezer Responsa, Vol 15, Chap. 70) rules Shev V’al Ta’aseh - sit and don't do.

Source: 
[Belfer, Israel. The Trolley Problem at a Crossroads: Halacha and NeuroEthics, JME Vol VIII no 2. October 2016, pp. 61-70.](https://www.academia.edu/30389010/The_Trolley_Problem_at_a_Crossroads_Halacha_and_NeuroEthics_JME_Vol_VIII_no_2._October_2016_pp._61-70)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot decide which life is more valuable, even is it yours against other (like someone willing to give a vital organ for transplant).

in the train example I saw an answer that you should leave to shamaim, if you cannot stop the train and need to decide right or left, flip a coin. but as mentioned in the previous answer I guess it would be a case of sitting and doing nothing. maybe flipping a coin would be in a case that you need to decide.

Comment: If you're steering the train and must pick one path then obviously choose the path that kills less people since there's no shev v'al ta'aseh either way, you should try to minimize deaths.

Comment: @ArielK: But you're already on one path. If you shev v'al ta'aseh, that path you are on will kill people. you're only active option is to switch tracks. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Railroad_switch

Comment: If that's the case, I assume shev v'al ta'aseh would also apply. Unless somehow by steering the train the person is already involved in doing something so maybe it would make it less of an action to steer one way?

Comment: Whatever it is, flipping a coin is definitely the wrong thing to do and perhaps a violation of ' לא תנחשו ולא תעוננו '.

Comment: Flipping a coin allows the result of chance. Now you are gambling with people's lives! Better to stay clear from the switch.