# Military Assessment center question - Group survival vs personal sacrifice vs prohibition of "casting dice"

Tags: halacha

A Halachic Question from an assessment center:

Your group (say 5 people) are standing in front of a  high wall of an embassy. An angry mob is moving fast in your direction. You are safe if you reach the embassy ground. To get in, one of your group must give assistance from the ground for the rest to climb high enough to overcome the wall. The person who does it will not be able to climb and will get kidnapped or killed by the mob.

Should none climb or is it allowed to "cast dice/draw a straw" in such situation if none volunteer to be the "helper"?

Thank you

Comment: [Welcome to Mi Yodeya](//judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887)! You might find [this highly-related question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/10062/the-trolley-problem-is-it-better-to-kill-1-person-or-let-5-die) helpful.

Comment: I don't remember where, but there is talk in the gemara about a case where a group of Goyim demand  a single Jew be given to them (from among a group) to kill, or the Goyim will kill all of the Jews

Comment: @Loani this? https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Terumot.8.11?lang=bi&with=Jerusalem%20Talmud%20Terumot&lang2=he

Comment: @RabbiKaii no, I think it was specifically talking about giving over a Jew to Goyim.

Comment: What do you mean by assessment center?

Comment: Assessment Center is a body, usually consisting of at least 3 people which selects candidates for officer/leadership Position in the Military or Economy, heavy Part of it are roleplaying games and psychological questions with stress and peer pressure. I think in Israel its called psychometric testing.

Comment: "casting dice" is gambling, a prohibition that has nothing to do with this situation. You're asking if you can choose one person to die if, otherwise, everyone will die, which is a completely different question.